# Is this a misuse of "composition over inheritance"?

Tags: inheritance, composition

The general sentiment seems to be that composition is preferable, in most cases, over inheritance, as it leads to less coupling. But for a case like this,

```
module Publishable
  def new?
    @content.created_at > freshness_threshold
  end
end

class Book
  include Publishable

  def initialize(content)
    @content = content
  end

  def freshness_threshold
    t = Time.now
    Time.new(t.year)
  end
end

class Magazine
  include Publishable

  def initialize(content)
    @content = content
  end

  def freshness_threshold
    t = Time.now
    Time.new(t.year, t.month)
  end
end
```

where the methods implemented by a mixin depend on the presence of certain methods (`freshness_threshold`) and instance variables (`@content`) in the including class, would it be better to use inheritance? This is a contrived example, but imagine there are additional methods in `Publishable` that also depend on methods/variables in the including class.

Would it be preferable to define an abstract parent class that `Book` and `Magazine` descend from?

Answer (score 4):

Mixins or traits are a *third* alternative to inheritance or composition. Whether they are better often depends on the particular implementation. The important feature of mixins or traits are that they are like abstract classes, but can be applied to multiple classes (and one class can consume multiple mixins). There are – in some implementations – some details regarding the method resolution order that are different between abstract classes and mixins, but otherwise from that they really are equivalent, up to the point that this difference is irrelevant if the language allows multiple inheritance (MI).

The thing where traits are really great is that they supply zero or more methods, and require zero or more methods. This makes using traits fairly straightforward. However, most languages don't have namespaces for methods – all definitions land in the same namespaces, which can lead to clashes between traits.

Your example doesn't even go that far, because your mixin only implicitly declares the requirements on using classes (that `freshness_threshold` must be a date, and `@content` must have a `created_at` field which must be a date). This is even worse than an abstract class in, say, Java – except that Java doesn't have MI, so you are *forced* to use composition when “inheriting” multiple behaviours.

In contrast, composition forces you to be more explicit about data flow. This is good, because your code becomes more obvious! In your particular example, the mixin only has a single method, so for all purposes it's equivalent to a free function (or `Proc` or whatever it's called in Ruby). This function requires two inputs: the `freshness_threshold` date, and the `created_at` date. Given such a free function `is_new(creation_date, threshold_date)`, it is now very simple to make this behaviour avaiable to your classes without having to pollute the public interface of these objects with a public `freshness_threshold` date. E.g. they could define

```
def new?
  t = Time.now
  return is_new(@content.created_at, Time.new(t.year, t.month))
end
```

If your objects depend on `is_new` as an explicit dependency, e.g.:

```
def initialize(content, is_new = is_new_default)
  @content = content
  @is_new = is_new
end
```

, then an important advantage of composition appears: we can dynamically supply a different implementation (without having to resort to reflection or similar), which allows us to easily and separately test both the `is_new` operation and the code that depends on this operation. This advantage is less obvious for a simple comparison as here or other “functionally pure” operations, but will be truly important if the dependency supplies external side effects, e.g. network requests, database queries, …. Unless the language has dependency management baked-in to the inheritance system or mixin system, this is hard to beat.

If `Book`s and `Magazine`s were both used in a polymorphic context where you'd need to find out whether they are `new?` without knowing if they are a `Book` or a `Magazine`, then defining a common interface that declares this method would be sensible (assuming a more statically typed language). However, interface inheritance is completely orthogonal to the inheritance vs. composition discussion.